# Autocomplete HTML Attribute Not Disabled for Password Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, passwords

Security scan of our server says

> Autocomplete HTML Attribute Not Disabled for Password Field.
>
> Fix: Correctly set the "autocomplete" attribute to "off"
>
> Reasoning: AppScan has found that a password field does not enforce
>   the disabling of the autocomplete feature

After seeing this report I have set `autocomplete=off` and  `AutoCompleteType="Disabled"` for username and password textboxes. But it makes no change. Browser asks for Remember password and if click yes, autocomplete feature is enabled there. How can I resolve this? Or is there any mechanism to force stop the browser for asking remember password?

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="tb_loginid" autocomplete="off"  AutoCompleteType="Disabled" runat="server" ForeColor="#5D7B9D"></asp:TextBox>
  <input type="password" style="display:none;"/>
  <asp:TextBox ID="tb_password"  autocomplete="off"  AutoCompleteType="Disabled" runat="server" ForeColor="#5D7B9D" TextMode="Password" >*</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: is this inside a form tag??

Comment: any chance that the browser is displaying cached data? try `hard refresh(ctrl+F5)` or different browser

Comment: @kowsikbabu cached data was cleared. and tried with different browsers. no effect

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the below attribute on the form tag(if this is inside a form-which it should be in all fairness)

```
<form method="post" action="YourAction" id="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: it is inside form tag. and already set autocomplete off. it still shows already entered usernames and it's passwords  <form method="post" autocomplete="off" id="form1" runat="server" >